# query group by with having and get results in two different columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table like these:

```
Name  Source ended_status date        Environment
House DC     1            2019/10/03  Pro
Cat   DC2    1            2019/10/05  Pro
Pen   DC     1            2019/10/03  Pro
Pen   DC     0            2019/11/07  Pre
```

I would like to get:

```
Source  Environment Ended_Status_with_1    Ended_Status_with_2
  DC        Pro               2                   0      
  DC        Pre               1                   0
  DC2       Pro               1                   0
```

So, they must be grouped by Source,Environment and I must calculate a summation of all that they have Ended_Status with 1 and all with ended status 2 and put in the same line.

How could I do that?

I can make query grouped by every ended_status but I can't put the two summations of ended status in same line.

Many thanks and sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    source,
    environment,
    sum(case when ended_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) ended_status_with_1,
    sum(case when ended_status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) ended_status_with_2
from mytable
group by
    source,
    environment
```

Comment: Wooo thanks, last question please. If I would like to have summation of the two ended status how could I do?

Comment: @absolute333: you can expand the logic, like: `sum(case when ended_status in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) ended_status_with_2`

Answer (score 1):

also, try below query

```
 select source,environment,sum(decode(ended_status,1,1,0)) ended_status_with_1,
    sum(decode(ended_status,2,1,0)) ended_status_with_2 from mytable
    group by source,environment
```